# После восстановления резервной копии Битрикс MySQL выдаёт ошибку

Tags: sql, база-данных, битрикс

Текст ошибки:

MySQL Query Error: SELECT U.*, DATE_FORMAT(U.TIMESTAMP_X, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') TIMESTAMP_X, IF(U.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 SECOND), 'Y', 'N') IS_ONLINE, DATE_FORMAT(U.DATE_REGISTER, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') DATE_REGISTER, DATE_FORMAT(U.LAST_LOGIN, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') LAST_LOGIN, DATE_FORMAT(U.PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY, '%d.%m.%Y') PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY , BUF.UF_NAME_CONPANY, BUF.UF_INN, BUF.UF_RS, BUF.UF_BANK, BUF.UF_OGRN, BUF.UF_LEGAL_ADRESS, IF(DATE(BUF.UF_DATE_REG)<>BUF.UF_DATE_REG, DATE_FORMAT(BUF.UF_DATE_REG, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), DATE_FORMAT(BUF.UF_DATE_REG, '%d.%m.%Y')) UF_DATE_REG, BUF.UF_PHONE_COMPANY, BUF.UF_POST_ADRESS, BUF.UF_DOCUMENT, BUF.UF_KPP, BUF.UF_KSCHET, BUF.UF_BIK, BUF.UF_MINI_NAME, BUF.UF_POSITION, BUF.UF_FIO, BUF.UF_CODE_OKPO, BUF.UF_CODE_OKVED, BUF.UF_CODE_OKFS, BUF.UF_DOGOVOR, BUF.UF_SECTIONS FROM b_user U LEFT JOIN b_uts_user BUF ON BUF.VALUE_ID = U.ID WHERE (1=1 AND ( U.LOGIN='alexweb' ) ) ORDER BY U.ID asc[[1054] Unknown column 'BUF.UF_SECTIONS' in 'field list']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверте запрос на наличие колоннки.

Указание на явную ошибку в запросе:

```
Unknown column 'BUF.UF_SECTIONS' in 'field list']
```